# Shortcut to focus on results when searching in 'Open...' [CMD+O] modal

Tags: macos, finder

When I open finder and then go to the search field I can get to the filtered results by hitting `TAB` and then `DOWN`.

This is not working when I search within the modal which appears when I want to open something for example in `sublime-text`. I always have to use my touchpad/mouse which I would prefer to avoid. Am I missing something trivial or is there a way how to get to the results just by using keys?

[image: search within the 'open...' modal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts, you need to enable `Full Keyboard Access` for `All Controls`.

You can also toggle the setting at any time using `Control` + `F7`

With this setting enabled, you should be able to tab into the results.

Comment: Thank you, it works! But need to press 3x`TAB` to focus on the results field. I tried it before this post already with `Ctrl+F7` but only checked for 1x`TAB`... Allowing full access for all controls has some disadvantages, why I'm not always using it, but I guess this is the only default available solution... Anyway you got me on the right path so I'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Also you should checkout [UIBrowser](http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser), it shows you the UI elements for scripting and you could write an AppleScript to select the area you want.  Then use automator to create a service which you can set a keyboard shortcut for.  Or [Fastscripts](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts) is a nice little app that you can use to set shortcuts to applescripts.